# How to add libraries installed with ExternalProject_Add to target includes

Tags: c++, cmake, external-project

I'm trying to include external libraries to a cmake project through `ExternalProject_Add`.  To try out this feature I've created a minimal working example that involves adding pugixml to the project with `ExternalProject_Add`. However, I'm having problems finding a way to add the library's header files from the external project's local installation (i.e., pugixml's headers) in the project's include path.

The project tree of the minimal working example is organized as follows:

```
.
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── main.cpp
```

In this project tree, `build` refers to the build directory and the path where cmake is called to generate the build.

The contents of `./CMakeLists.txt` are as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(pugixml
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/zeux/pugixml.git
        INSTALL_DIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/extern_install/pugixml
        CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<INSTALL_DIR>
)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

In the above example I've added pugixml as an external project that is to be installed within the project's binary dir, whose file will be used by an executable stored in `./src`. Thus, the contents of `./src/CMakeLists.txt` are:

```
project(foo)

add_executable(foo main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo ${pugixml_LIBRARIES})
include_directories(${pugixml_INCLUDE_DIR}) # this part doesn't work
```

This is precisely the part I'm having problems.  I've assumed that once the external project was added and installed that `ExternalProject_Add` would have defined some convenience libraries to help refer to library files and include directories.  However, that doesn't work.  Does anyone know what's the right way of using `ExternalProject_Add` to include external libraries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake - linking to library downloaded from ExternalProject\_add()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351609/cmake-linking-to-library-downloaded-from-externalproject-add)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this will not work at all. The build of the external project is done at build time not during CMake configure/generate. The hint is `The ExternalProject_Add function creates a custom target to drive download, update/patch, configure, build, install and test steps of an external project:` ([from CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/module/ExternalProject.html))

Hence You will have to define all the variables yourself. See also: [CMake - linking to library downloaded from ExternalProject_add()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351609/cmake-linking-to-library-downloaded-from-externalproject-add) (I'd actually mark this as a duplicate of the linked question as the problem is the same)

BTW: I do also dislike the way this was done. This way one cannot simply use `find_package` etc.

The intended way to use this is a "super-build project": Define 1 CMakeLists where you only have `ExternalProject_Add`s for all dependencies AND your project. Then it will work with `find_package`.