# cmake: How to conditionally add an external project?

Tags: cmake

Please consider below `CMakeLists.txt`.

I am adding an external project if I am unable to find `FOO`; `mylib1` and `mylib2` depends on `FOO`.

This works if I am doing `make`, it sets up `FOO` if not found and proceeds towards `mylib1` and `mylib2`.

However if I run `make -j4` it does not quite work, as more workers are available it rushes to do `mylibX` while `foo` is being setup - end result is `mylibX` builds fails.  Which brings me to my question:

In cmake, what is the idiomatic way to conditionally include a `ExternalProject_Add()` call?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(myAweSomeLibs VERSION 1.0)

find_library(FOO
        NAMES foo
)

if (FOO)
    message("Found FOO")
else()
    message("Foo not found. Adding external project")
    include(ExternalProject)
    ExternalProject_Add(foobar
      GIT_REPOSITORY    git@github.com:FooCo/FooBar.git
      GIT_TAG           origin/release/1.2.3
    )
endif()

add_subdirectory(mylib1)
add_subdirectory(mylib2)
```

Comment: `more than one -j option` "-j" option? Most probably you improperly set up dependencies and this is unrelated to how you setup your `ExternalProject_Add`.

Comment: OK.. I am also trying to get the dependency `FOO` installed if not found. Could you pls show me the idiomatic way to accomplish this?

Comment: Idiomatic way for use ExternalProject is described in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29324527/3440745). With that way even `make -j` would work correctly.

Comment: And idiomatic way for use results of `find_library` see there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10550334/3440745. As you can see, **both** your branches could create an IMPORTED target, which can be used by your other libraries in the **same way**.